# Sinin does not return the right number forhow many times a function got called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have a code as follows:

```
 public async cleanUpCachedData(){
    
    const queries = await this._searchesDatastore.getArchivedSearches();
    queries.forEach(async query => {
        try{
            // try catch for each is neccessary 
            await this.handleCacheCleanup("columns", query._id);
            console.log("################")
            await this.handleCacheCleanup("json", query._id);
            console.log("################")
            await this.handleCacheCleanup("stix", query._id);
            console.log("################")
            await this.handleCacheCleanup("summary", query._id);
            console.log("################")
            await this.handleCacheCleanup("timechart", query._id);
            console.log("################")
```

and I wrote a test:

```
  it("Successful handling cache data clean up process", async () => {

    const searchDatastoreObj = searchesDatastore;
    const getArchivedSearchesStub = sandbox
      .stub(searchDatastoreObj, "getArchivedSearches")
      .returns([{_id: "11111"}]);
    const obj = initCache(
      loggingService,
      searchesDatastore,
      resultsDatastoreObj,
    );

    const test = sandbox
    .stub(obj, "handleCacheCleanup").returns(true)
    
    await obj.cleanUpCachedData();
    expect(getArchivedSearchesStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(test.callCount).to.equal(5);
    
  });
```

As you I have 5 handleCacheCleanup function call and I can see ################ printed 5 times but the test claims that it runs twice

```
  1) test cache cleanup by Total disk space
       Successful handling cache data clean up process:

      AssertionError: expected 2 to equal 5
      + expected - actual

      -2
      +5
```

I am really confused any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have it as async, the `queries.forEach` is being treated as sync and Promise resolve/rejection being ignored. Possible way to adjust this is using `Promise.all()`.

```
await Promise.all(queries.map(query => {
    try{
        // try catch for each is neccessary 
        await this.handleCacheCleanup("columns", query._id);
        console.log("################")
        await this.handleCacheCleanup("json", query._id);
        console.log("################")
        await this.handleCacheCleanup("stix", query._id);
        console.log("################")
        await this.handleCacheCleanup("summary", query._id);
        console.log("################")
        await this.handleCacheCleanup("timechart", query._id);
        console.log("################")
    } catch (e) {}
})
```

It executed the 5 calls to your point of console logging, but the test case completed before all of promises resolved. `forEach` is not async, so it got executed, but didn't wait for all promises inside to complete.

Comment: Thank after updating it works but can please explain more why mine did not return 5 calls ? I am still a bit confused